# Find word in List and Delete it

Tags: prolog

I need find a Word in list of char and delete it from that.

The predicate *ocurre([List],[Word],[CleanList])*.

```
[List] is a list of elements for example [a,b,c,d].
[Word] contains in a list the word that I must find in List for example [b,c]
[CleanList] return List with out Word (in the example [a,d])
```

The Program is:

```
ocurre([X|LS],[X|P],Aux):- ocurre(LS,P,Aux),!.
ocurre([X|LS],[Y|P],Aux):- concatenar(Aux,[X],Aux2),
                           ocurre(LS,[Y|P],Aux2).
ocurre([],[],Aux):-!.
ocurre([],P,Aux):-!.
ocurre(LS,[],[Aux|LS]):-!.


concatenar([],X,X):-!.
concatenar([X|Y],R,[X|M]):- concatenar(Y,R,M).
```

So, when I consult `ocurre([a,b,c,d] , [b,c] , L).` My program return `L=[]` and It must return `L=[a,d]`. I don't know what it's wrong. I appreciate your help

Comment: `delete` is doing exactly this.

Comment: Why all the cuts? You should remove those. If they are there because results were not what you expected, then that's the wrong use for a cut. Right off, your base cases are not logical. `ocurre([], [], Aux)` says that if you have an empty list and you remove words in another empty list, then the result is anything (`Aux`, uninstantiated). That doesn't make sense. Why isn't the rule,`ocurre([], [], [])`? Likewise with your other base cases. I suspect you have lots of singleton variable warnings which you should address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can get rid of all useless cut operators. You could rewrite your program without cuts and also you don't need the `concatenar/3` predicate:

```
ocurre([],_,[]).
ocurre([H|T],[],[H|T]).
ocurre([X|LS],[X|P],Aux):- ocurre(LS,P,Aux).
ocurre([X|LS],[Y|P],[X|Aux]):- dif(X,Y),ocurre(LS,[Y|P],Aux).
```

Example:

```
?- ocurre([a,b,c,d] , [b,c] , L).
L = [a, d] ;
false.
```

The problems with your implementation was first of all base cases, you only need tthe two base cases above for empty first list and empty first second list, all other cases are included in the recursion.

Also as I understood what you were trying to do was that when you find an element to add in the third list you concatenate the third list with the new list and passed as a new parameter. In this case you use the third list as an accumulator where you need to initialize in the beginning as the empty list. So instead of all this could just instantiate the third list-Result during the recursion, for example the rule:

```
ocurre([X|LS],[Y|P],[X|Aux]):- dif(X,Y),ocurre(LS,[Y|P],Aux).
```

simple says if X and Y are different the call ocurre with the rest of the list e.g LS and with second list [Y|P] and you have instantiated the current first element of third list: [X|Aux] with X and continue with the rest e.g Aux.

Comment: I think it would help the OP to add some explanation as to where they went wrong with their implementation, and include some explanation/definition of your rules for clarity.

Comment: @ chinocejas , glad to help!!

Answer (score 0):

a library([lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists)) based alternative:

```
?- [user].
ocurre(List,Word,CleanList) :-
|:       append([Left,Word,Right], List),
|:       append(Left,Right,CleanList).
|: 
|: ^Dtrue.

?- ocurre([a,b,c,d] , [b,c] , L).
L = [a, d] ;
false.
```